# Delegate function doesn't return value

Tags: vb.net, function, delegates, return, return-value

I might be missing something obvious, but I'm not able to return a value with a delegate.

```
Private Delegate Sub ChangeTextDelegate(tb As TextBox)
Private Sub ChangeText(tb As TextBox)
    If tb.InvokeRequired Then
        tb.Invoke(New ChangeTextDelegate(AddressOf ChangeText), tb)
    Else
        tb.Text = "NEW TEXT"
    End If
End Function
```

Sub Delegate works well.

```
Private Delegate Function TextLengthDelegate(tb As TextBox) As Integer
Private Function TextLength(tb As TextBox) As Integer
    If tb.InvokeRequired Then
        tb.Invoke(New TextLengthDelegate(AddressOf TextLength), tb)
    Else
        Return tb.TextLength
    End If
End Function
```

But this Function Delegate doesn't seem to work since `i == 0` after `dim i = TextLength(myTextBox)`, even though `tb.TextLength == 68`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not returning the value if the Invoke *is* required.

Try this instead:

```
Private Delegate Function TextLengthDelegate(tb As TextBox) As Integer
Private Function TextLength(tb As TextBox) As Integer
    If tb.InvokeRequired Then
        Return CInt(tb.Invoke(New TextLengthDelegate(AddressOf TextLength), tb))
    Else
        Return tb.TextLength
    End If
End Function
```

However, you might find this code easier as you don't have to define a separate delegate:

```
Private Function TextLength(tb As TextBox) As Integer
    If tb.InvokeRequired Then
        Return CType(tb.Invoke(New Action(Of TextBox)(AddressOf TextLength), tb), Integer)
    Else
        Return tb.TextLength
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It actually works, .net can make implicit conversions

Comment: @Arty - It wouldn't compile with `Option Strict On`, it does now.

Comment: @Arty If it worked before, you **must** switch `Option Strict On` *now*, in the project options and globally. Working without `Option Strict` is like handling a gun with the safety switched off.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I will

Answer (score 1):

Doesn’t VS warn you about your code since it doesn’t return a value when invoking the delegate?

```
tb.Invoke(New TextLengthDelegate(AddressOf TextLength), tb)
```

You have to return the value returned by `Invoke`, and since `Invoke` [returns an `Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to cast the value:

```
Dim result = tb.Invoke(New TextLengthDelegate(AddressOf TextLength), tb)
Return DirectCast(result, Integer)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it was obvious.